# Этимология слова "козы(а)" в идиоме "отставной козы барабанщик"

Tags: этимология

Какова, на ваш взгляд, этимология слова "козы(а)" в идиоме "отставной козы барабанщик"?

Answer (score 3):

Выражение неоднократно обсуждалось, приходится признать, что единого мнения нет.
Вот одна из версий.

> Отставной козы барабанщик
> Так называли в XIX веке людей без определенных занятий, а иногда и просто маленьких, забытых людей, кое-как кормящихся какими-нибудь случайными и никому не нужными поделками. Откуда взялось это шуточное определение?
> Почти до самой революции в глуши можно было увидеть бродячую труппу нищих или полунищих: поводыря с ученым медведем, показывавшим разные «штуки», «козу» - человека, на голове которого было укреплено грубое подобие козьей головы из мешковины, и «барабанщика», часто из отставных солдат, барабанным боем призывавшего «публику».
> Оказаться на положении «отставного барабанщика при козе», то есть потерять и эту работу, было уже окончательным пределом бедствия. Вероятно, в языке бродячих трупп и надо искать корни нашего образного выражения.

http://www.otrezal.ru/catch-words/310.html

Даю именно этот источник, поскольку там есть несколько альтернативных версий.

Answer (score 0):

Никто и никогда уже не узнает , кто и в связи с чем придумал это выражение - все версии которые я читал вполне реальны и каждая может претендовать на первоочерёдность .. Добавлю ещё смысловой нагрузки на эту тему .. Слово ,,Отставной,, может означать не только человека вышедшего в отставку , а и например ту же отставную - приставную ( то есть отставленную от чего-либо )лавку-козу .. Может означать и человека отставшего (ОТСТАВной)от чего-либо или от кого-либо .. Слово ,,коза,, может означать как всё ту же лавку-козу , кази (судью) так и глупую бабу и т.д. и т.п .. А слово ,,барабанщик,, в этом выражении , может означать не только барабанщика который бьёт в барабан , а и барского банщика (бара-банщик) который на той же козе-лавке парит барина в бане , парой берёзовых веников и его движения сродни тому же барабанщику .. И все житейские ситуации ,которые подходят под эти многочисленные смыслы слов ,можно в шутку выразить именно ,как ,,Отставной козы барабанщик,,! - Народ у нас талантливый и чувство юмора ему не занимать .. =)